# Dynamic loading of KML files into Google Maps

Tags: kml, google, mapping

I'm looking to load KML files that I have created in to Google Maps. I have loaded them to dropbox to test and made public. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong in the following call:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgpbcqdnpgqpr2q/Fraud_Google_API_MAP.kml?dl=0"
```

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps website (maps.google.com) no longer supports loading KML files via a URL parameter like that ("?q=http://example.com/myfile.kml"). An alternative is to make a simple web page that loads a map via the Google Maps Javascript API, and add your KML file as a layer.  Documentation and example scripts are available at these links:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml

Also, as the other answer indicated, the DropBox link you're using opens the DropBox web page for the file, and does not go directly to the KML file. You need a URL that will simply download the file. I think you can do that easily, since it looks like when you change the "dl" parameter to be "dl=1" that it will directly download the KML file. I haven't tried hosting KMLs on DropBox, but I think that could work with the Maps API.

Answer (score 1):

The KML files can't be read directly by Google when they're in Dropbox, even though they are public, they need to be downloaded first.

Only [supported files types that allow preview](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/sort-preview/file-types-that-preview) would be readable